# maven automatically includes gwt compiler output to war exploded artifact

Tags: gwt, maven-3, artifacts

I use JetBrains IDEA 12.0, maven 3.2. And seems that maven automatically add gwt compiler output to my default project artifact war exploded. How to turn off it?

Comment: You'd have to give more info: is only when opened in IntelliJ or independent? (i.e. happens when running Maven from the command line) how's your POM and gwt-maven-plugin configured? And most importantly: what behavior are you expecting?

Comment: It is a good practice to follow up on your question in stackoverflow. Please post update if your were able to resolve your question and close the question if you found an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Is it not the point to add gwt compiler output "modulename" into **war** artifact.

If you are trying to block out some unused gwt output like "deploy" folder in WEB-INF then use **deploy**  flag to redirect the ourput to folder that does not get included in war artifact.

In maven - `<deploy>${project.build.directory}/gwt-symbols-deploy</deploy>` tag in your gwt-maven-plugin configuration.

You can also filter out your war artifact contents - http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html